# Undefined variable: data (laravel multiple image upload)

Tags: laravel-5

[image]

This is my controller for multiple image upload, I am getting an error saying, data is undefined on json_encode(data),, can some give me a solution?

Comment: Please add your code instead of the image

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = [];

    if($request->hasfile('image') as $image){
     foreach($request->file('image') as $id => $image){
                $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $name = $id.time().'.'.$ext;
                $path = public_path('\property\');
                $image->move($path, $name);
                $data[$id] = $name;
            }
    }
```